# Не отображается изображение в браузере

Tags: html

Имею следующий код HTML

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Моя первая страничка</title>
</head>
    <body>      
        <img src="C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\buba.png" width="200">
    </body>
</html>
```

В редакторе все отображается нормально, однако и в браузере ПК и на мобильном устройстве картинка отображается вот так:
[image: ![введите сюда описание изображения]
Как исправить?

Comment: а вы его выложили на хостинг куда-то или что?Как вы его открываете с мобилы?

Comment: Через IP адрес захожу и смотрю.

Comment: вставил все это в блакнот сохранил как html , закинул картинку на рабочий стол. Открыл через хром, картинку вижу. Что вы там деалаете не понимаю

Comment: html код написан в JSP файле, который работает с сервлетом

Comment: т.е вы хотите чтобы браузер на клиенте должен локально сходить к себе и загрузить такую картинку по такому пути ? А она у него там есть ?

Comment: Так это абсолютный путь. Картинка там есть. Сервлет делается с помощью Java ee, поместив картинку в одну папку с JSP файлом результат был такой же.

Answer (score 0):

Добавь картинку в папку с доком html и просто напиши путь src="buba.png", если в папку с доком html добавишь папку в которой будет эта картинка и назовём её к примеру abub то путь src="abub/buba.png"  и так далее.

Answer (score 0):

Используй относительный или абсолютный путь. Если относительный, загрузи картинку в папку проекта и пиши путь, например, src="public/images/buba.png". Или же абсолютный путь, ссылка на другой ресурс в интернете src="https://www.refugeesrespond.org/dadaabwikimedia/images/a/a9/Example.jpg"

Comment: А почему не загружается с пути как у меня? с абсолютного?